# Retrieving specific fields using the Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the Java API for Elasticsearch.
Having saved entities into indexes, it is possible to retrieve them together with the complete source. However, I only want to retrieve selected fields, and that is not working.

The folowing sample code:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("my-index")
   .setTypes("my-type")
   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
   .setFetchSource(true)
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field1", "1234"))
   .addFields("field1")
   .execute()
   .actionGet();

for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()){
   Map<String, SearchHitField> fields = hit.getFields();
   System.out.println(fields.size());
   Map map = hit.getSource();
   map.toString();
}
```

will retrieve the correct entities from the index, including the complete source.

For example, this is a snippet of the response :

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : 1301,
  "max_score" : 0.99614644,
  "hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "my-type",
  "_id" : "AU2P68COpzIypBTd80np",
  "_score" : 0.99614644,
  "_source":{"field1":"1234", ...}]}
}, {
```

However, while `response.getHits()` returns the expected number of hits, the `fields` and `source` within each hit is empty.

I am expecting each hit to contain the field specified in the line:

```
.addFields("field1")
```

Commenting out the line

```
.setFetchSource(true)
```

will cause the response not to include the source at all.

The version of Elasticsearch is 1.5.0

The following is the maven dependency the Java API:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
   <artifactId>elastic4s_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Obiously, for performance reasons, I don't want to have to retrieve the complete entity.
Does anyone know how to limit the retrieval to selected fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 49):

You can specify the fields you need using the [`setFetchSource(String[] includes, String[] excludes)` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/get/GetRequestBuilder.java#L148). Try this instead

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("my-index")
   .setTypes("my-type")
   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
   .setFetchSource(new String[]{"field1"}, null)
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field1", "1234"))
   .execute()
   .actionGet();

for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()){
   Map map = hit.getSource();
   map.toString();
}
```

`map` will only contain the fields you've specified.

Note that `.setFetchSource("field1", null)` (if you need a single field) or `.setFetchSource("field*", null)` (if you need several wildcarded fields) would work, too.

Comment: @user1052610 were you able to use the suggested solution?

Comment: Didn't work for me with ElasticSearch 5.x. :(
It returns an empty "_source" field in the response, and doesn't copy "field1" as a real field.

Comment: @cs94njw That's not supposed to have changed [according to the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/c98e3f60f78fb47ae7482d96952f2dbabd1d6d49/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/get/GetRequestBuilder.java#L127-L131). Feel free to create a new question referencing this one, so we can sort it out.

Comment: Could one filter down to child properties of a json field value with this approach?

Comment: @Yoshimitsu yes definitely, like `parent.child.grandchild`

Comment: @Val does using `setFetchSource` improve latency here? Or does it just trim down the full doc to specific fields? Also, if I'm more interested in improving latency, would aggregating be a better choice?