# Elasticsearch Java API index document count

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know the curl command to get the information I need.

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices/alerts*
```

and the output is

```
yellow open alerts_1502744517_1 5 1 25 0 642.3kb 642.3kb 
yellow open alerts_1502744517_0 5 1 25 0 741.8kb 741.8kb 
yellow open alerts_1502744882_0 5 1 27 0 679.8kb 679.8kb
```

What I need is the index name and the document count, which in this case is the 6th column (the 25, 25, and 27). How do I make the equivalent call using the java API?

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to get all the indices

```
String[] indices = client.admin()
                             .cluster().prepareState().get()
                             .getState().getMetaData()
                             .getConcreteAllIndices()
```

Then traverse them all and get the count for each indices.

Take a look into this class if you want to make a REST call: [RestIndicesAction.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/cat/RestIndicesAction.java#L64) or the [cat package](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/cat)

Comment: I was hoping for something that would get the index names and the document counts all in one go so I wouldn't have to keep querying for each index.

Comment: Second option with cat REST API can do that with one query.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try, but after some research on [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-java) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476493/retrieving-specific-fields-using-the-elasticsearch-java-api). I found a solution that could work using this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code

```
Node node = nodeBuilder()
  .clusterName("elasticsearch")
  .client(true).node();
Client client = node.client();
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("my-index")
   .setTypes("my-type")
   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
   .setFetchSource(new String[]{"field1", "field2"}, null)
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field1", "1234"))
   .execute()
   .actionGet();

for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()){
   Map map = hit.getSource();
   map.toString();
}
```

Let me know if you have any error

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Written on ElasticSearch 6.2.4 with Java 8.

```
/*for document count*/
long docCount = client.admin().indices().prepareStats(indiceName).clear().setDocs(true).execute().actionGet().getPrimaries().getDocs().getCount();
```