# Filter out nested objects ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

Is it possible to filter out unrelated nested objects? The use case is that you have a single parent but, the parent has multiple children. Say for example for a particular parent...there's 100 children; I need a way to filter out the particular children so that out of a 100, I get a subset of that result.

**UPDATED**

Ran the following query

```
GET /dev/doc/_search?typed_keys=true
{"_source":{"includes":["reviews"]},"query":{"nested":{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"reviews.userId":{"value":"339c8add-4278-4acd-905e-64b9acabc71a"}}}]}},"path":"reviews"}}}
```

However, I'm getting back the following results:

```
"reviews": [
            {
              "score": 0,
              "friendlinessOfStaff": 1,
              "amenities": 2,
              "grounds": 2,
              "reviewDate": "2018-07-03T02:00:34.8735726-07:00",
              "qualityOfCare": 4,
              "activities": 2,
              "facilityReviewReplies": [],
              "id": "56a4bac2-85d0-4ccf-aba2-fd9ff74fb3a5",
              "message": "blah blah blah",
              "userId": "339c8add-4278-4acd-905e-64b9acabc71a",
              "cleanliness": 4
            },
             {
              "score": 0,
              "friendlinessOfStaff": 1,
              "amenities": 2,
              "grounds": 2,
              "reviewDate": "2018-07-04T12:01:22.228658-07:00",
              "qualityOfCare": 4,
              "activities": 2,
              "facilityReviewReplies": [],
              "id": "f2f1b84e-bc1d-4e9c-b6d5-bdc578cb1b5f",
              "message": "blah blah blah",
              "userId": "7f1d389d-1316-4058-9857-ca51ecd9f5f8",
              "cleanliness": 4
            }
           ]
```

As you can see the last object from this list has "userId": "7f1d389d-1316-4058-9857-ca51ecd9f5f8" which does mot match however, the filter is still returning the values. Any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking how to filter which inner nested objects get returned.  Andreas's answer will help if you are asking how to chose which columns to return without filtering the data in those columns.

To return only the nested objects that match your query you can use `inner_hits`.  Basically just add it to your query clause and you should get the matching inner objects.  There are some more configuration options for paging, etc that you can optionally add.

```
GET index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "field_name",
            "query": { ... },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

[inner_hits reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)

Comment: Documentation for NEST for inner hits: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/inner-hits-usage.html

Comment: @RussCam & Ryan.. I've **updated** my original post. Running the nested query still doesn't show the desirable results.

Comment: @Dean your updated query doesn't include `inner_hits: {}` for the nested query

Comment: @RussCam OK..I'll update and share the results...thanks.

Comment: @RussCam thanks much..`inner_hits` definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using?

You probably want something like this (java): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30476650/5335131

Otherwise there is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

You can specify fields to include and exclude like so:

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": [ "obj1.*", "obj2.*" ],
        "excludes": [ "*.description" ]
    },
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andreas. The problem is...can I query on nested objects? Also my client is NEST.

Comment: Yes, you can query on nested objects, have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-nested-query.html